Filtering a list based on the values of another list in Polars
Let's say I have the following DataFrame:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'values': [[0, 1], [9, 8]],
    'qc_flags': [["", "X"], ["T", ""]]
})

I only want to keep my values if the corresponding qc_flag equals "".
Does anyone know the correct way to go about this?
I've tried something like this:
filtered = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("values").list.eval(
        pl.element().filter(
            pl.col("qc_flags").list.eval(
                pl.element() == ""
            )
        )
    )
)

I would expect to get 'values': [[0], [8]], but then I just end up with this error:

ComputeError: named columns are not allowed in `list.eval`; consider
using `element` or `col("")`



pl.Expr.list.eval to evaluate expression within list.
pl.arg_where() to find indexes where value is "".
pl.Expr.list.gather() to take sublist by indexes.

df.with_columns(
   filtered = pl.col.values.list.gather(
      pl.col.qc_flags.list.eval(pl.arg_where(pl.element() == ""))
   )
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ values    ┆ qc_flags  ┆ filtered  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [0, 1]    ┆ ["", "X"] ┆ [0]       │
│ [9, 8]    ┆ ["T", ""] ┆ [8]       │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


This was the fastest solution. Thank you so much! It processed approximately 138,000 rows in less than 1/20th of a second!

You can add a temporary column to track which element of the lists comes from, explode the lists into proper series, do the filter, and then group by that column again:
(df
    .lazy()
    .with_row_index()
    .group_by("index")
    .agg(
        pl.col.values.explode().filter(pl.col.qc_flags.explode() == "")
    )
    .drop("index")
    .collect())

Output:
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ values    │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [0]       │
│ [8]       │
└───────────┘


that's an interesting way of doing it - you use group_by at the beginning just to get access to aggregation methods right away, so you can explode()/implode() within group without exploding the whole DataFrame. Quick performance test also shows that this is a bit faster than list.eval() (not sure about large DataFrames though)

I was looking at @orlp answer and I think you can also make it a bit different - no group_by() needed, only

pl.Expr.explode().
pl.Expr.filter().
pl.Expr.implode().
pl.Expr.over(), using pl.int_range() and pl.len() to create an index.

This way it's a bit more natural to add it as a new column without transformations of other columns of the DataFrame.
df.with_columns(
    filtered = pl.col.values.explode().filter(
        pl.col.qc_flags.explode() == ""
    ).implode()
    .over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ values    ┆ qc_flags  ┆ filtered  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [0, 1]    ┆ ["", "X"] ┆ [0]       │
│ [9, 8]    ┆ ["T", ""] ┆ [8]       │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


It is also possible with the List API.
.arg_true() gives the indexes of the true values.
df.with_columns(
   pl.col.qc_flags.list.eval((pl.element() == "").arg_true())
     .alias("indexes")
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ values    ┆ qc_flags  ┆ indexes   │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str] ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [0, 1]    ┆ ["", "X"] ┆ [0]       │
│ [9, 8]    ┆ ["T", ""] ┆ [1]       │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

.list.gather() to extract the values
df.with_columns(
   pl.col.values.list.gather(
      pl.col.qc_flags.list.eval((pl.element() == "").arg_true())
   )
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ values    ┆ qc_flags  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [0]       ┆ ["", "X"] │
│ [8]       ┆ ["T", ""] │
└───────────┴───────────┘

